# Current and Electricity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

Is it possible that a current flows across a resistor although there exists no difference?
If yes than how? Is this not a contradiction of **ohms** **Law**?

Comment: You probably have a reference were you read that this is possible. It would be helpful, if you could provide that reference and describe the system which you are interested in.

Comment: yes if the resistance is zero--ideal superconductor.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, Ohms law is not actually a law like a law of gravity e.g., its realy just a statement about certain properties of certain materials. So in a superconductor Ohms law is not at force, so to say. Across a resistor or at the end points of a resistor there must be a potential difference in order for current to flow. Across a perfect conductor it does not have to be so. As in any situation, when there is no force that oposes the motion you need no force just the starting push. But when there is resistance like in a resistor you need the force id est change of the potential. In electric circuit analysis we assume that wires are perfect condutors so they act to opose the outside field. So inside a conducting wire there is no field and no potential difference. But electrons are moving because there is no resistance and battery is always doing its magic, suplying electrons at one end and taking them away at the other end. With som resistor in a circuit current reaches its steady state very quickly. In a steady state kinetic energy of the electrons is not increasing but the work is still being done by the battery. So in a resistor this work is being converted to other forms of energy, heat and light radiation. So in this steady state we can say that potential energy drop per unit charge passing by in a resistor is the same as the one on the battery id est which battery can provide. Its a bit like falling through the air, in one moment you reach terminal velocity and then you are not changing your potential energy into kinetic but into heat. So current can not flow through zero potential difference in a resistor but it can in a conductor.